# How to change channel dimension of am image?

Tags: pytorch

Suppose I have torch tensor with `shape = [x,y,z,21]` where `x = batch_size, y = image_width, z= image_height`. The above tensor represents batch of images with 21 channels. How should I convert it to `size = [ x,y,z,3 ]` ?

Comment: Why do you have a 21 channel image? What do the channels do ? There is no unique way to do this

Comment: I am working on Pascal voc 2012 dataset for semantic segmentation and as there are 21 classes present, each channel represents score of that particular class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[x,y,z,21] -> [x,y,z,1] -> [x,y,z,3]

for segmentation results **predicts** with size [x,y,z,21]

segmentation class index **result** with size [x,y,z,1]

```
# for pytorch, the right format for image is [batch, channels, height, width]
# however your image format [batch, height, width, channels]
result=predicts.argmax(-1)
```

the index combie the color map will help you! view [voc color map](https://gist.github.com/wllhf/a4533e0adebe57e3ed06d4b50c8419ae) for detial